# Flutter: Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'android\app\build.gradle' (.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\bns44vh0ng7mnmeckuwo1ww24)

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I am trying to start my android emulator, but I get this error:

```
Build file '..\android\build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file '..\android\app\build.gradle' (..\.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\bns44vh0ng7mnmeckuwo1ww24).
      > BUG! exception in phase 'conversion' in source unit '_BuildScript_' class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression (org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression and org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @42d80b78)
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is a flutter project.
It is working for web.
I think it might be something with the sdk version, because flutter updated and I had to change the Sdk version in the pubspec.yaml, because that was when the error occured.

Hope someone can help.